# Snowflake: bind variable for object not set

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create some wrappers around system functions. However I seem to be overlooking something as trying to declare the following procedure:

```
create or replace secure procedure test(arg1 varchar)
returns varchar not null
language sql
execute as owner
as
begin
    return IDENTIFIER(:arg1);
end;
```

Results in the error `Error: Bind variable for object "arg1" not set (line ...)`.

I have an other procedure that looks similar to me that does work.

```
create or replace secure procedure create_wh (wh_name varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
comment = '<string_literal>'
execute as owner
as
begin
    create warehouse if not exists IDENTIFIER(:wh_name)
      warehouse_size = xsmall
      auto_suspend = 60
      auto_resume = true
      initially_suspended = true;

    return 'SUCCES';
end;
```

What is the difference between these 2 and why does the second one work, while the first one throws an error when I try to create it.

Comment: is `arg1` declared and assigned a value before calling ?

Comment: @Tushar The error occurs when trying to create the procedure.

Comment: I understand that;
The error message you encountered suggests that there is a problem with the variable "arg1". It may not have been declared or assigned a value correctly. This issue can occur when the variable is not defined or when its value is not provided when the procedure is invoked.

Are you already assigning value like this ?

`DECLARE arg1 VARCHAR(100) := 'some_value';`

Comment: @Tushar I am not assigning anything. I am under the assumption that arg1 is a param send into the procedure that I can then instantly use inside of it. I edited the question with a procedure that does work, but to me is exactly the same.

Comment: the problem is :argv1  in your sect it is part of a query else you write only argv1 without :

Answer (score 0):

First example  `return IDENTIFIER(:arg1);` is trying to return value of independent identifier call, while second is a correct usage with DDL (creation of virtual warehouse).

`IDENTIFIER` alone does not work as function and should not be treated as such:

> [Literals and Variables as Identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal)
>
> **In Snowflake SQL statements,** in addition to referring to objects by name (see Identifier Requirements), you can also use a string literal, session variable, bind variable, or Snowflake Scripting variable to refer to an object
>
> Usage Notes
>
> **Although IDENTIFIER(...) uses the syntax of a function, it is not a true function and is not returned by commands such as SHOW FUNCTIONS.**

```
CALL ABS(-1);
-- 1

CALL IDENTIFIER('a');
-- Unknown function IDENTIFIER
```

Comment: I am still missing the part as to how I should rewrite the procedure.

Comment: @SomeDutchGuy  Purely hypothetically what should be the output of standalone `IDENTIFIER('a')` and what is the data type of that expression( VARCHAR is for strings)?

Comment: The input for arg1 will be a varchar (so the output of the identiefier call should be a varchar). I am trying to write a wrapper around system functions that take 1 or 2 variables, so I can create some system users that are scoped down in their access. The real procedure (this is a minimal example) will take 2 varchars and return the result of a call to a system function.